# Showing invisible window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a window with some process and visualization but I want this window to be hidden on startup but still performing it's work. I've managed to achieve this using simple code

```
SomeWindow.Show();
SomeWindow.Hide();
```

But the issue is this code causing startup flickering. I can't fight this neither in Windows Forms, nor in WPF. Is there more elegant way to show hidden/invisible window?

#### UPDATE

I want the window to show in TaskBar but only when it's visible. Window is performing task that relies on rendering that will be performing in time regardless of visibility and user should be able to see it's state like it was open all the time.

Comment: When I call `Show` form it will be visibile. And without this call my visualization and depending process won't work.

Comment: But it won't resolve taskbar issue (I want this window to show in TaskBar).

Comment: If you really need to call Show(), then of course it will flicker.  The entire purpose of the method is to, well, show the form... make it visible.  Will it work to just create the form object?  `MyForm SomeWindow = new MyForm();`  Are you needing trigger certain events?

Comment: I can't see a single thing in your requirements that isn't default window behavior.

Comment: And what about running window minimalized without showing it on task bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SomeWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false; // not shown on taskbar set to true if you want to show form on taskbar
SomeWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; // set window state as minimized
SomeWindow.Show();
```

You don't even need to hide it.

This is winforms version I did not test it in WPF.

Update:

If `Hide()` is not done after `Show()` window is on opened windows list (Alt+Tab). To prevent this do:

```
SomeWindow.Hide();
```

Comment: This leaves the window as a visible minimized box at the bottom of the screen.  It is possible to then move it out of the visible area, but it is still accessible in the visible windows list, e.g. Alt+Tab, Win+Tab.  The user can still activate it.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you but I do not see such behavior (on windows 10) what OS you are using? Maybe you do it on WPF project? Is this second window of first one?

Comment: Windows 10.  Winforms.  Either window.  I was letting the first load as normal then loading the second window on an event.  But if I change the first window to have the properties you indicated, it does the same thing--the only difference is that it starts **behind** all other windows.  if you minimize or move your other windows, you will find it.  Even if not, it should still be appearing in the Alt+Tab window list.

Comment: @CPerkins You are right about Alt+Tab to prevent this behavior you need to do `SomeWindow.Hide();` after show. But I can not find this little window that I am curries about. Also I know that you can remove window (even fully show on screen) from Alt+Tab list as I done this in the past but right now I don't remember how.

Comment: Funny, the next time I re-ran the program the minimized box was also not visible at first. I suspect that Windows Desktop has some sort of window-memory and is re-hiding it(?).  Anyway, to at least see what I am talking about, run your program, use Alt-Tab to open the hidden window.  Now re-minimize it (without changing `SomeWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false`) and you will likely see the window collapse to a little box in the lower-left of your screen. To make it easier, have only your Visual Studio open and not maximized.

Comment: @CPerkins True when I re-minimalize I can see box, but I never seen it immediately after show.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Logman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210629/1548895) I've created extension method to show invisible window

For Windows Forms:

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static void ShowInvisible(this Form form)
    {
        // saving original settings
        bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
        FormWindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

        // making form invisible
        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        // showing and hiding form
        form.Show();
        form.Hide();

        // restoring original settings
        form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
        form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
    }
}
```

or for WPF:

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static void ShowInvisible(this Window window)
    {
        // saving original settings
        bool needToShowInTaskbar = window.ShowInTaskbar;
        WindowState initialWindowState = window.WindowState;

        // making window invisible
        window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

        // showing and hiding window
        window.Show();
        window.Hide();

        // restoring original settings
        window.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
        window.WindowState = initialWindowState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vadim Ovchinnikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44215597/4919610) for WPF was a great start, but didn't work for me eventually for two reasons: Show() and Hide() are synchronous methods which is a problem when you want to have that window precreated while no other window is open (for there is no Dispatcher executing these requests); furthermore restoring the original values had to be performed later, otherwise a quick flicker was still noticeable. Then again, I had to restore the value of ShowInTaskbar asynchronously; otherwise the taskbar entry was missing, but curiously only when running in the Visual Studio debugger.

The following helper class does the job for me:

```
public class InitiallyInvisibleWindow
{
  private readonly Window _window;
  private bool _origShowActivated;
  private bool _origShowInTaskbar;
  private WindowState _origWindowState;

  public InitiallyInvisibleWindow(Window window)
  {
    _window = window;
  }

  public void ShowInvisible()
  {
    _origShowActivated = _window.ShowActivated;
    _origShowInTaskbar = _window.ShowInTaskbar;
    _origWindowState = _window.WindowState;

    _window.ShowActivated = false;
    _window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    _window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

    _window.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    _window.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  }

  public void RestoreVisible()
  {
    _window.ShowActivated = _origShowActivated;
    _window.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
      {
        _window.ShowInTaskbar = _origShowInTaskbar;
        _window.WindowState = _origWindowState;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a window for this task? Why not just start up a class on another thread and have it do the work?

If a window is really needed just have the window when opened request data from that custom task.

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

Task.Run(()=>myClass.Start());
```

Comment: Because my task relies on visualization, not vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine without "flicker".  As Ed mentioned, the Taskbar button behaves as you would expect without addition settings or code.

```
//Assuming SomeWindow is System.Windows.Form object
SomeWindow.Opacity = 0.0;
SomeWindow.Show();
SomeWindow.Hide();

//Elsewhere in code when you want to display the window
SomeWindow.Opacity = 1.0;
SomeWindow.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it shows and hides in taskbar and I face blinking on startup.